# Error inflating Class exception Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.forms

I have downloaded a sample Cross Platform application sample from the payment provider JudoPay from the following [link](https://github.com/Judopay/Xamarin-Sample-App/blob/master/samples/Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml) I am new to Xamarin and mobile development

I have tried to deploy the project to an emulator within Visual Studio 2019 but every time it loads the Main Activity on the line base.OnCreate(savedInstance) as shown below:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   LoadApplication(new App());
 }
```

I get the error:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout'
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this error or understand the cause?

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

you could follow below steps:

right click your Android project -> **Properties** -> **Android Opition**

if **Code shrinker** is `r8`,disable **Enable Multi-Dex**，otherwise if you enable **Enable Multi-Dex**,set **Code shrinker** to `Null` or `ProGuard`